# Удвоение внутренних ссылок на сайте

Tags: php, html, чпу

Есть меню на сайте, вот его код:

```
<a href="/uslugi-dizajnera-i-tsenyi" title="Услуги и цены">Услуги</a>
<a href="/uslugi-dizajnera-i-tsenyi/paket-ekonom" title="Пакет услуг 'Эконом'">Пакет "Эконом"</a>
<a href="/uslugi-dizajnera-i-tsenyi/paket-standartnyj" title="Пакет услуг 'Стандарт'">Пакет "Стандартный"</a>
<a href="/o-dizajne/" title="О дизайне">О дизайне</a>
<a href="/o-dizajne/digest-novosti-dizayn-studii-interera" title="Дайджест дизайн студии">Дайджест</a>
<a href="/o-dizajne/stili-v-interiere" title="Стили в интерьере">Стиль в интерьере</a>
```

Страницы подгружаются в индексный файл через include_once:

```
case 'uslugi-dizajnera-i-tsenyi':
    include_once("service.php");
break;
case 'uslugi-dizajnera-i-tsenyi-studii/paket-ekonom':
    include_once("uslugi/ekonom.php");
break;
case 'uslugi-dizajnera-i-tsenyi-studii/paket-standartnyj':
    include_once("uslugi/standart.php");
break;
case 'o-dizajne/':
include_once("o-dizajne.php");
    break;
case 'o-dizajne/digest-novosti-dizayn-studii':
     include_once("digest.php");
break;
case 'o-dizajne/digest-novosti-dizayn-studii/kak-rogdaetsa-svoy-interier':
    include_once("digest/kak-rogdaetsa-svoy-interier.php");
break;
```

После анализа сайта через онлайн сервис, он находит что на сайте более 5000 ссылок, хотя на самом деле их не более 50. Показывает ссылки вот такого плана:

```
1. o-dizajne/o-dizajne/digest-novosti-dizayn-studii-interera-conception-v-kieve/uslugi-dizajnera-i-tsenyi/paket-ekonom
2.o-dizajne/o-dizajne/digest-novosti-dizayn-studii-interera-conception-v-kieve/uslugi-dizajnera-i-tsenyi/paket-standartnyj
```

и так далее. В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 0):

Если при анализе сайта поисковиком есть 5000 ссылок, то они должны быть видны на странице - хоть в консоли, но видны. И их не может в таком случае там быть 50.
А почему так получается - сложно сказать не имея ссылки на сайт и не видя кода. Может у тебя меню генерируется цикле, который дает столько итераций, может сайт взломан (вордпрессы-ждумлы и подобное) и вирус или левый плагин набивают его рекламными ссылками - тут хз, информации мало.
Смотри консоль, или сохрани страницу как текст - и посмотри, что там по факту. С этого можно начать.